# Access object from container view controller

Tags: objective-c, uicontainerview

Below is shown navigation stack.

`UIViewController` -> `UIContainerViewController` -> `UINavigationViewController` -> `UIPageViewController` -> `UIViewController`

The parent view (First view controller) contains a button and child view (Last view controller) contains `UITextField`.

What I want to do is that when I press the button in parent view, the text from the child view text field should be stored in a `NSString` object in parent view.

What I tried is:

```
ChildViewController *CV = [self.childViewControllers lastObject]

ChildViewController *CV = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"]
```

None of the above working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use notifications, since the relationships between controllers are hard to handle, when you press the button post a buttonPressed notification and when the child VC received the notification post a needToStoreString notification and put the string in notification's userInfo and so the parent VC can know.

Comment: Notifications can help and aren't a bad way to communicate between objects, but I wouldn't do it on everything. And at least you have delegates to communicate ...